# How to know Android SDK version for current device in Android Studio 3.x?

Tags: android, android-studio

In old version of Android Studio I can see Android SDK version for current device in dialog box "Select Deployment Target".

[image: Android Studio 2.x]

Now I see device name only.

[image: Android Studio 3.x]

Comment: For me, newly-created AVDs include the SDK version in the name, e.g. "Pixel 3 API 29". I guess one option is to make sure you name your AVDs according to that convention from now on.

Comment: @stkent I mean physical device.

Comment: Ahh; I like you just see "Google Pixel 3 XL" for my personal device... no idea how to add the SDK version to that UI I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Open toolbar "Logcat" and click on list "devices".

[image]